# Even after converting a dataframe into dictionary, its type remains as a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe like the one below

```py
--> playstore_df['App'].value_counts()

ROBLOX                 9
8 Ball Pool            7
Bubble Shooter         6
Helix Jump             6
Zombie Catchers        6
```

On the left we have app names, and on right, its count (i.e. how many times it has occurred in the dataset)

I stored it into a variable called `app_count`. To convert this into a dictionary, I used the `to_dict()` function.

```py
--> app_count.to_dict()
```

The following was the output:

```py
{'ROBLOX': 9,
 '8 Ball Pool': 7,
 'Bubble Shooter': 6,
 'Helix Jump': 6,
 'Zombie Catchers': 6}
```

But when I check the type of `app_count` using the following function:

```py
--> type(app_count)
```

It gives the output as:

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: Hey, try this : 

    test=app_count.to_dict()
    type(test)

Answer (score 1):

[`DataFrame.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) does not operate in-place. It will return a dictionary containing the `DataFrame`'s content (like you saw when using `app_count.to_dict()`), but the original df will remain unchanged. To save the modifications, you need to store them back to the original variable like so:

```py
app_count = app_count.to_dict()
```

Now, `app_count` will be a dictionary.

---

Side note: if you don't need the original Series/DataFrame, you can also get the dictionary in one line:

```py
app_count = playstore_df['App'].value_counts().to_dict()
```